# find $n$ in $x = \sqrt[n]{y}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I'm not very experienced at math, though I find it very interesting most of the time. I am writing a program where I need to find $n$ in $x = \sqrt[n]{y}$, given $x$ and $y$. I have implemented it using a loop, with a 'guess and check' type of method. I keep feeling, however, like there is already some simpler way to do this. What am I looking for here?

Comment: Use $n=\log_x y$

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I figured this out when I started looking more in to logarithms. I was going to come comment the same thing, but it looks like you beat me to it by almost a whole day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is even then we have that $y>0$ and $x>0$ and

$$x=y^{1/n}\to \log x=\frac1n \log y \to n=\frac{\log y}{\log x}$$

If $n$ is odd then we can have $y<0$ and then $x<0$. On that case we can multuply both sides by $-1$ and then

$$-x=(-y)^{1/n}\to |x|=|y|^{1/n}\to n=\frac{\log |y|}{\log |x|}$$

So, the general solution is

$$n=\frac{\log |y|}{\log |x|}$$

Comment: I thought it might be logarithms, but I couldn't find anything that said so, and have never actually used them outside a math class (where they were never actually explained very well).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that $x,y >0$ you can just take logarithms
$$
x = \sqrt[n]{y}\Leftrightarrow \log x = \frac 1n \log y \Leftrightarrow n = \frac{\log y}{\log x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Besides the exact answers the others posted, the general approach you've already tried (trial and error) includes an established [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), which converges rather quickly.